# reactive WebSocketClient data publishing

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to read data from websocket using `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` but I just can't hook up on to it's api. The problem is that all data I receive are available in the inner part of the lambda-style websockethandler (#1) but I want to make them available to the subscribers after .subscribe on client.execute(..) (#2)

```
WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
        client.execute(
                URI.create(URL),
                session -> session.send(
                        Mono.just(session.textMessage(pairRqStr)))
                        .thenMany(session.receive()
                                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                                .map(this::toResp)
                                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> throwable.getMessage())
                        )
                        .log() // #1
                        .then()
        )
                .log()
                .subscribe(System.out::println); // #2
```

a bit lost and new to this, so, please, guide me.

Answer (score 0):

To send or receive messages, you must first connect to the channel. Thats why `client.execute` returns `Mono<Void>`, which means it returns no data, it just signalizes completion or failure of handskahe. 
If it would return eg. `Flux<WebSocketMessage>`, how would you know if the handskake completed succesfully?

If you want to access channel outside lambda, you cant do it by implementing handler method:

```
        Consumer<WebSocketMessage> printingConsumer = webSocketMessage -> System.out.println(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

        client.execute(URI.create(URL), session -> handle(session, printingConsumer));
    }


    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session, Consumer<WebSocketMessage> consumer) {
        return session.receive()
                .doOnNext(consumer::accept)
                .then();
    }
```

Comment: well if handshake wouldn't complete ok, I would throw the message (being websocketclient) and direct it to some .onError**(..)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did finally, but still don't like it much:

```
    private Flux<WebSocketMessage> requestData(String req) {
        WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
        return ConnectableFlux.create(sub -> {
            client.execute(
                    URI.create(URL),
                    session -> session.send(
                            Mono.just(session.textMessage(req)))
                            .thenMany(session.receive().doOnNext(sub::next))
                            .then()
            )
                    .log()
                    .subscribe();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me